# Incorrect order of Vue components after copy operation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have several accordions (every one is a single Vue component) and they are expanded by default. There's also a 'copy' function allowing to make a duplicate of every component.

```js
Vue.component("Accordion", {
  template: "#accordion-template",
  
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: true
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      this.open = !this.open;
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  data: {
    devices: [
      {
        name: "a", description: "first"
      },
      {
        name: "b", description: "second"
      },
      {
        name: "c", description: "third"
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    copy: function (device) {
      var index = this.devices.indexOf(device) + 1;
      var copy = {
          name: device.name + "_copy",
          description: device.description + "_copy"
      };

      this.devices.splice(index, 0, copy);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-root">
    <div class="device" v-for="device in devices">
        <accordion>
            <div slot="acc-head">
                <span>{{ device.name }}</span><br/>
                <button @click="copy(device)">copy</button>
            </div>
            <div slot="acc-body">
                {{ device.description }}
            </div>
        </accordion>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="accordion-template">
    <div>
        <slot name="acc-head"></slot>
        <button @click="toggle">Open: {{ open }}</button>
        <div :class="open ? 'active' : 'hidden'">
            <slot name="acc-body"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

When all accordions are collapsed (in other words 'open: false') and I try to duplicate an accordion from the middle of list (for example b), I expect appearing of the new component named 'name'_copy and it must be expanded by default. But instead of this, the new component has the same values of all attributes as the duplicated one and the last component in the list becomes expanded.

How can I solve this issue?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3ydt1m7/

Comment: Add a key in your `v-for` loop: `v-for="device in devices" :key="{something here}"`. Use an unique value. If you don't have, you can try  `v-for="(device, index= in devices" :key="index"`

Comment: @Al-un could you please provide an example because it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Al-un thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added an answer to explain why the `:key="..."` is needed. Mea culpa, you should **not, definitively not** use `v-for="(device, index= in devices" :key="index"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Add a key in your `v-for` loop: `v-for="device in devices" :key="{something here}"`. Your key must be unique and identify each device, even after device copy

### Code

Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/Al_un/9cradxvp/. For debugging purpose, I changed few things:

- I put `device` as `props` of `<accordion>` so that I can use device properties in `console.log`
- Copying device is now emitted from `<accordion>`. [Vue doc on listening to child component events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events)
- I have added `mounted()` and `updated()` hooks. More about [Lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks)
- Each device has an ID

### Long answer

#### About list rendering

If key is not provided in `v-for` loop, Vue does not know how to update a List. From [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key):

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item.

Let's consider your list (I have added one element)

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "a"},
  {id: 2, name: "b"},
  {id: 3, name: "c"},
  {id: 4, name: "d"},
]
```

Now, let's copy node "b". Without `:key="device.id"`, the console output is

```
4: d is mounted
3: c is updated
5: b_copy is updated
```

With `:key="device.id"`, the console output is only:

```
5: b_copy is mounted
```

Basically, without keys, there are:

- two updates: `c` becomes `b_copy`, `d` becomes `c`
- one insert: `d` is created

Consequently, the last element is recreated every time you proceed to a copy. As `open` default value is `true`, obviously, `d` has `open = true`.

If each element has a `:key="device.id"`, then only element `b_copy` is created

To check that, remove the `:key="device.id"` from my fiddle and see what happens in the console

#### Selecting a key

As the key must uniquely identify your device, you should not use index as a key as device index in the array changes whenever you copy a device

Additionally, an ID field is preferred because there is no guarantee that your devices names are unique. What if you initialise the list with

```
[
  { name: "a"},
  { name: "b"},
  { name: "a"}
]
```

From a functional point of view, this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

When working with Vue and lists you should add a [key prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) to the element with v-for. Using the key like this, let's Vue know that you mean a specific element.

```
    <div class="device" v-for="device in devices" :key="device.name">
```

I believe the reason for this is that due to performance reasons Vue by default adds a new element as the last element and then updates the data in the other nodes. Thus, the new element that you add is actually the last one in the list which has open set as true.

Comment: It is not actually due to performances reasons: without a key, Vue does not know what to update nor what to create. Behind the hoods, it actually update all nodes from the inserted position and create an additional node. Please check my answer for more details

Comment: @Al-un Isn't the decision to create an additional node to the end due to performance reasons as DOM access is considered slow and it is tried to minimize?

Comment: I have updated the example in my answer to illustrate my point. It is not just a simple node creation. It appears to be "appended" because new element are added at the end of an array. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to your code:

Instead of providing the "device" object and searching for its index you could just pass the index directly.

This is what i mean: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy5Lopf8/3/)

```js
Vue.component("Accordion", {

  template: "#accordion-template",

  data: function() {
    return {
      open: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.open = !this.open;
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  data: {
    devices: [{
        name: "a",
        description: "first"
      },
      {
        name: "b",
        description: "second"
      },
      {
        name: "c",
        description: "third"
      },
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    copy: function(index) {
      var device = this.devices[index];
      var copy = {
        name: device.name + "_copy",
        description: device.description + "_copy"
      };

      this.devices.splice(index + 1, 0, copy);
    },
    remove: function(index) {
      this.devices.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.device {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.device {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #a3a3a3;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-root">
  <div class="device" v-for="(device, index) in devices" :key="device.name">
    <accordion>
      <div slot="acc-head">
        <span>{{ device.name }}</span><br/>
        <button @click="copy(index)">copy</button>
        <button @click="remove(index)">remove</button>
      </div>
      <div slot="acc-body">
        {{ device.description }}
      </div>
    </accordion>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="accordion-template">
  <div>
    <slot name="acc-head"></slot>
    <button @click="toggle">Open: {{ open }}</button>
    <div :class="open ? 'active' : 'hidden'">
      <slot name="acc-body"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```